# SQL Server database migration to new location

Tags: sql-server

I want to migrate a production SQL Server database which is more than 400gb in size to a new environment at a different hosting provider.

How can I do that without a lot of downtime?

Answer (score 0):

Some options.

- Create a full backup on system A, copy the backup to system B and restore it there.
- Detach the database on system A, copy all db-files (mdf,ldf, ndf) to system B and attach them there
- Import and export data wizard

Remember to also re-create jobs, dts-packages etc where relevant

Answer (score 0):

- You can use mirroring...

  1. Install new sql server instance and create mirror db on this new server from prod db 2. Wait until db's are synchronized and turn off the old server 3. Now remove mirror from new server and recover the mirrored db.

[Moving SQL Server database from old production server to new server](https://serverfault.com/questions/301437/moving-sql-server-database-from-old-production-server-to-new-server)

- Or go thorough the below blog which states 8 step to migrate safely without downtime

[8 Steps to Safely Migrate a Database Without Downtime](https://dzone.com/articles/safe-database-migration-pattern-without-downtime)